# Java, send and receive a file with socket: is it necessary use bufferedinputstream and bufferedoutputstream?

Tags: java, sockets, bufferedinputstream, bufferedoutputstream

I'm trying to write two methods for send and receive file with java socket in a client-server application and I have some doubts:

I use `FileInputStream` and `FileOutputStream`. Are `BufferedInputStream` and `BufferedOutputStream` better?

```
static protected long send_file(File file, DataOutputStream output) throws IOException, FileNotFoundException, SecurityException
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    long count = 0;
    int nread = 0;

    FileInputStream file_input = new FileInputStream(file);

    output.writeLong(file.length());

    while((nread = file_input.read(buffer)) != -1) 
    {
        output.writeInt(nread);

        output.write(buffer, 0, nread);
        count += nread;
    }

    output.flush();
    file_input.close();

    return count;   
}


static protected long receive_file(File file, DataInputStream input) throws IOException, FileNotFoundException, SecurityException, EOFException
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    long dim_file = 0;
    long count = 0;
    int nbyte = 0;
    int nread = 0;
    int n = 0;

    FileOutputStream file_output = new FileOutputStream(file);

    dim_file = input.readLong();

    while(count < dim_file) 
    {
        nbyte = input.readInt();

        nread = input.read(buffer, 0, nbyte);
        if(nread == -1)
        {
            file_output.close();
            throw new EOFException();
        }

        while(nread < nbyte) 
        {
            n = input.read(buffer, nread, nbyte-nread);

            if(n == -1)
            {
                file_output.close();
                throw new EOFException();
            }

            nread += n;
        }

        file_output.write(buffer, 0, nread);

        count += nread;
    }

    file_output.flush();
    file_output.close();

    return count;   
}
```

I don't understand the necessity of `BufferedInputStream` and `BufferedOutputStream`:

In the first method, I use a buffer of 1024 byte and first I fill it with `FileInputStream.read(byte[] b)` and then send it to socket with `DataOutputStream.write(byte[] b, int off, int len)`.

In the second method idem: first I fill the buffer with `DataInputStream.read(byte[] b)` and then write to the file with `FileOutputStream.write(byte[] b, int off, int len)`.

So why use `BufferedInputStream` and `BufferedOutputStream`?
In this way, if I understand how they work, I write bytes first in my buffer and then `BufferedInputStream` and `BufferedOutputStream` copy bytes in their buffer.

Comment: Necessary, no. Advisable, yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you dont use buffered streams Java IO will make an operating system call each time you write /read a byte whether it is writing / reading to file or socket which is extremely inefficient.

Comment: Every time you call a read or write *method*. Not the same thing.

Comment: Why? FileInputStream.read() - native, FileOutputStream.write(byte) - native

Comment: But I use my own buffer with FileInputStream.read(byte[] b) and DataInputStream.read(byte[] b).

Comment: If you use read / write  with byte array (as in your example) you dont need buffered streams.

Comment: There are indeed native methods, but not just for single bytes.

Answer (score 2):

It is not about better. They offer differnt things. While the fileoutputstream writes to a file, the BuffereOutputStreams writes to a buffer (hence the names :) ).
You should combine them, to get best performance. e.g.

```
BufferedOutputStream bo = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("output.txt"))
```

Your programm will then first write everything to a buffer, and only dump it into the file when you flush the buffer

Comment: So I will have:

...socket DataInputStream--->buffer[1024]--->BufferedOutputStream--->buffer[?]---->FileOutputStream---->File. 

But what buffer size should i use for BufferedOutputStream? The default?